# Como nomear constraints no MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou tentando nomear `constraints` no `MySQL` mas sem sucesso, estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
create table if not exists pessoas
(
    id int auto_increment,
    nome varchar(30) not null,
    data_nascimento date,
    constraint pk_pessoa primary key(id)
) default charset = utf8;
```

Quando executo o comando `show create table pessoas` minha `constraint` não está definida e quando tento fazer `alter table pessoas drop index pk_pessoa` recebo um erro. Onde estou errando?

Comment: Se possível clique em **[edit]** e poste seu erro.